# Example for Poco framework Notification Center

Tags: c++, poco

I have been trying to understand `Poco` framework and I am on Linux (using Codeblocks IDE)

I am specifically trying to incorporate notification center in my program to send global notifications and I read some info from the link here as well.
http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.NotificationCenter.html but that doesn't give any solid example there as well.

Can somebody point to a simple example on how to send notification from a certain and listen (?) to those notification in a separate class>

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 examples that I think it is helpful for your question.

1. From Poco, please read https://pocoproject.org/slides/090-NotificationsEvents.pdf and it provides a simple example.
2. A good example code at http://poco.roundsquare.net/2010/07/05/poconotificationcenter/ although it's Janpanese but the code is not. :)

Hope it is good enough for you. Good luck!